# Pyplot - How do I plot multiple lines on the same graph when list lengths for one axis are not consistent?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to plot multiple lines on the same graph, one of the axis lists consists of dates and the other is a list of the numbers corresponding to each of the dates. However, when I go to plot the second line, the dates list is different in contents and length from first line plotted. So to try and fix this I put all of the dates used into 1 array and used this for the y-axis. This then left me with the issue of the x-axis never being the same length of as the y-axis causing an error. In an attempt to fix this I tried the following:

```py
while len(y) != len(dates): 
    y.insert(0, 0)
plt.plot(dates, y)  # plots the line for x (dates) and y
```

This fixes the error however the graph now plots 0's when it should be plotting 1's.

[image: image of Graph here]

The graph should be plotting on 0.1 instead of 0.0

So what I'm asking is how would I fill the y-axis list with the zero's in the correct position, relevant to the dates, rather than putting all of the zero's at the beginning of the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plot the two sets of data in separate calls. Here's an example:

```
from datetime import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

derby_dates = [datetime(2020, 3, 1),
               datetime(2020, 3, 2),
               datetime(2020, 3, 3),
               datetime(2020, 3, 6)]
derby_cases = [1, 10, 7, 12]
nottingham_dates = [datetime(2020, 3, 1), datetime(2020, 3, 2)]
nottingham_cases = [2, 5]

plt.plot(derby_dates, derby_cases)
plt.plot(nottingham_dates, nottingham_cases)
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

That plots like this:

[image: Plot image]